# Using Strings and Double Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm brand new to programming, so please bear with me. I need to create a program using while loops, one String array, and three double arrays. My output should be something like this:
java Average 4

Joe 3 5 2

Tim 4 1 5

Jane 6 3 2

Jack 8 3 5

Jill 5 4 9

Mike 6 7 3

Ctrl-Z

Joe 3 5 2 3.33

Tim 4 1 5 3.33

Jane 6 3 2 3.67

Jack 8 3 5 5.33

I'm basically needing a program to read input with names, and three numbers. The output should print the names and numbers I inputted and then the average of each set of numbers. I'm able to create a class file, but after I press Ctrl+z, the program doesn't output anything.

```
public class Average { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        
        
        String [] names = new String [n];
        
    
        double [] a = new double [n];
        double [] b = new double [n];
        double [] c = new double [n];
        
        int counter = 0;
        
        while (counter < n) {
            String [] run = StdIn.readAllStrings();
            double [] value = StdIn.readAllDoubles();
            counter++;
        }
        
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        double value = StdIn.readDouble();
            sum += value;
            n++;
            
            double average = sum / n;
            
        StdOut.print(names);
        StdOut.print(value);
        StdOut.printf("%.2f", average);
       
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some info about the StdOut / StdIn class?

Comment: In normal java syntax we would use the System.in input stream and the System.out output stream

Comment: StdOut/StdIn are used in the same way that Scanner is used to read input from a user. If you look within my post, you can see where my input is what comes before the Ctrl-z. The computer should then automatically output what comes after Ctrl-z.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, but something that comes to my mind is that numbers can be read as strings, thus `StdIn.readAllStrings()` might be reading in all of the numbers too?

Comment: So instead of reading the names I'm typing, it's only reading the numbers I enter?

Comment: the opposite way - wouldn't it be reading *all* of it as strings?

Comment: I thought it would be reading all the names I type and assign the value to my string array, but I guess I'm misunderstanding this function. I'm changing some things around now.

Comment: @gizmo.java, if `StdIn.readAllStrings()` is the same as in [StdIn.readAllStrings()](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html#readAllStrings--) then the function will read all the strings input by the user, but the values will still need to be mapped (somehow manually or with a function) to each of the names.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\n"));
scanner.forEachRemaining(s -> {
  if(s.replace(" ","").equals(""))return;
  System.out.println(s+" "+Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).skip(1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average().orElse(0));
});
```